# Reading files with non-ASCII characters in their names on Windows

Tags: r, file-io, character-encoding

I want to process a large number of files with R, and some of the files contain non-ASCII characters in their names as in the following.

- 2002_88_2_Stępniewski.txt
- 2003_100_2-3_Saı̈dou.txt

However, I cannot read the file names properly with `list.files()`.

```
> (files <- list.files("~/files", full.names = TRUE))   
[1] "C:\\Users\\murakama\\Documents/files/2002_88_2_Stepniewski.txt"
[2] "C:\\Users\\murakama\\Documents/files/2003_100_2-3_Sai¨dou.txt"
```

Naturally, I cannot read the files based on the names, either.

```
> scan(files[1])
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\murakama\Documents/files/2002_88_2_Stepniewski.txt': No such file or directory

> scan(files[2])
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\murakama\Documents/files/2003_100_2-3_Sai¨dou.txt': No such file or directory
```

The issue is unique to running R on Windows, as it does not occur when I run R on Mac. Does anyone know how to read these files in Windows' R?

Comment: Try setting the encoding of your result.  `Encoding(file) <- "UTF-8"`. See `?Encoding`

Comment: It does not seem to help.

    `> Encoding(files[1]) <- "UTF-8"`
    `> scan(files[1])`
    `(same error as the above)`